# How to show popup box in windows mobile application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a windows mobile application in which I want to show popup box containing `DataGrid` control of showing particular details when user clicks on a button in a form.

I am using `ShowDialog()` method but it is working.

Can anyone suggest me how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am using ShowDialog() method but it is working. ?

Comment: Is this a compact framework app? If so you should edit your tags, as it's nothing to do with asp.net. Also your question is not clear - is it working, or isn't it? You should show some code for people to be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, my solution was to create a custom popup class.

```
public class Popup : Control
{
    private class Const
    {
        public const int Height = 100;
        public static Color BarFrameColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
        public static Color BarShadowColor = Color.Black;
        public static Color BackColor = SystemColors.Info;
        public static Color ForeColor = SystemColors.InfoText;
    }

    // [ gdi objects ]
    private Bitmap m_bmp;
    private Pen m_penShadow, m_penFrame;

    private Panel panel;
    private VScrollBar vScrollBar;
    private Label lblText;
    private bool scrolling;

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return lblText.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lblText.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Scrolling
    {
        get
        {
            return this.scrolling;
        }
        set
        {
            this.scrolling = value;
        }
    }

    public Popup()
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.ForeColor = Const.ForeColor;
        this.BackColor = Const.BackColor;
        this.Height = Const.Height;

        this.panel = new Panel();
        this.panel.BackColor = Const.BackColor;
        this.panel.Location = new Point(2, 2);

        this.vScrollBar = new VScrollBar();
        this.vScrollBar.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(vScrollBar_ValueChanged);

        this.lblText = new Label();
        this.lblText.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.lblText.Text = "";

        this.panel.Controls.Add(lblText);
        this.Controls.Add(vScrollBar);
        this.Controls.Add(panel);

        CreateGdiObjects();

        this.Scrolling = false;
    }

    private void CreateGdiObjects()
    {
        // [ gdi objects ]
        this.m_penShadow = new Pen(Const.BarShadowColor);
        this.m_penFrame = new Pen(Const.BarFrameColor);
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);

        // [ calculate layout ]
        this.Left = 0;
        if (this.Parent != null)
        {
            this.Width = this.Parent.Width;
            this.Top = this.Parent.Height - this.Height;
        }

        if (this.Scrolling)
        {
            this.vScrollBar.Size = new Size(12, this.Height - 4);
            this.vScrollBar.Location = new Point(this.Width - 2 - this.vScrollBar.Width, 2);

            this.panel.Size = new Size(this.Width - 4 - this.vScrollBar.Width, this.Height - 4);
            this.vScrollBar.Minimum = this.panel.Top;
            this.vScrollBar.Maximum = this.panel.Height;
            this.vScrollBar.Visible = true;

            this.lblText.Size = new Size(this.panel.Width, this.Height * 3);
        }
        else
        {
            this.panel.Size = new Size(this.Width - 4, this.Height - 4);
            this.vScrollBar.Visible = false;
            this.lblText.Size = this.panel.Size;
        }


        this.BringToFront();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // [ draw progress on memory bitmap ]
        CreateMemoryBitmap();
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.m_bmp);
        DrawControl(g);

        // [ blit to screen ]
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.m_bmp, 0, 0);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // [ don't pass to base since we paint everything, avoid flashing ]
    }

    private void CreateMemoryBitmap()
    {
        // [ see if need to create bitmap ]
        if (this.m_bmp == null || this.m_bmp.Width != this.Width || this.m_bmp.Height != this.Height)
            this.m_bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    }

    private void DrawControl(Graphics g)
    {
        g.Clear(this.BackColor);
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
        g.DrawRectangle(this.m_penShadow, rc);
        rc.Inflate(-1, -1);
        g.DrawRectangle(this.m_penFrame, rc);
    }

    private void vScrollBar_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lblText.Top = -this.vScrollBar.Value;
    }
}
```